# Problem with fetching data in React, Assignment to constant variable

Tags: reactjs, fetch-api

I just started to learn React and was trying to fetch some random data. i created a useState and have two values : `const [name, setName] = useState([]);`
when i try to do `name : response.json();`
I get an error that assignment to a constant variable, I'm following a tutorial which is doing the same.
surprisingly when I create a constant variable with a different name, it works. I only can't assign the `name = await response.json();`
Thank you

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { ReactDOM } from "react";

const FetchData = () =>{

    const [name, setName] = useState([]);

    const fetchNames = async () =>{

        const url = `https://randomuser.me/api`;

        try {
            
            const response = await fetch(url);
            name = await response.json();
            console.log(name);
           setName(name);
        
        } catch (error) {
            
            console.log(error);
        }
    }

    useEffect(()=>{

        fetchNames();
    },[])

    return(

        <div>

        </div>
    );
}

export default FetchData;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check my example, as I understand you want to use name inside the try as variable not from state so you should add `const`. I also mapped the response in your render which you can see the results. Here also codesandbox example https://codesandbox.io/embed/friendly-ishizaka-57i66u?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [name, setName] = useState([]);

  const fetchNames = async () => {
    const url = `https://randomuser.me/api`;

    try {
      const response = await fetch(url);
      constname = await response.json();
      console.log(name);
      setName(name?.results);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchNames();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      {name.map((el) => (
        <>
          <p>{el.email}</p>
          <p>{el.phone}</p>
        </>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

there are 2 things that might help with this confusion

1. any variable created using `const` will forever hold the value it had when it was declared, so for eg if we have `const x = ""`, we later can't do something like `x = "something else"`
2. in the snippet you shared `name` is a "state variable". state variables should NEVER be updated directly, state updates must happen through setState function only(i.e. `setName` in this case)

   this is the part in official docs that talks about it https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#do-not-modify-state-directly , https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html#updating-state